# How to logout user in AWS Cognito with Asp.net-WebAPI

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am writing a web api in c# which performs login for cognito. However I am not able to find the logout option, I see there is one for Javascript, But how to perform the logout through c# web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these:-

- [AdminUserGlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderAdminUserGlobalSignOutAdminUserGlobalSignOutRequest.html)
- [GlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderGlobalSignOutGlobalSignOutRequest.html)
- REST API call to [/logout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) endpoint

Comment: Thanks! Updated the links.